# BST only first node can be found

Tags: c++, arrays, search, binary-search-tree

Every node has a data&meaning array, right&left pointer.and, it looks like second node is added (I knew by print count), but when I search for it, there is no result. Also, if I tried to add more nodes.

in main

```
BST tree;
char sw[10];
char A[ ]={"BST"};
char Am[ ]={"Binary Search Tree"};
tree.maketree(A,Am);
char B[ ]={"COM"};
char Bm[ ]={"commerce"};
tree.maketree(B,Bm);
    cout<<"Search: ";
    string inputword;
    cin>>inputword;
    strcpy(sw, inputword.c_str());
    tree.BST_Retrieve(sw);
```

retrieve function: _retrieve return node if found and BST_Retrieve print the meaning

```
NODE* _retrieve (char key[],NODE*node)
{
    if (node)
    {
        if (strcmp(key,node->data)<0)
            return _retrieve (key, node->left);
        else if (strcmp(key,node->data)>0)
            return _retrieve (key, node->right);
        else
            return (node);
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}// _retrieve
bool BST_Retrieve (char key[])
{

    NODE *node;
    if (! root)
        return false;
    node = _retrieve (key,root);
    if (node)
    {
        printf("%s",node->meaning);
        cout<<endl;
        node=node->right;
        if (node) {
            cout<<"\nNext word is: ";
            printf("%s",node->data);
        }
        return true;
    } 
    else
        return false;
}
```

thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your retrieval code looks fine, so I would check your tree building code.

Also, I wouldn't mix `printf` and `cout`.

```
cout << node->meaning << endl;
```

and

```
cout << "Next word is: " << node->data << endl;
```

will do just fine.

Other suggestions:

```
strcpy(sw, inputword.c_str());
tree.BST_Retrieve(sw);
```

can be safely shortened to:

```
tree.BST_Retrieve( inputword.c_str() );
```

since you're not trying to store the pointer returned by `c_str`.  You will have to change your methods to take `const char *key` instead of `char key[]`, however.

**EDIT**:  It appears your retrieval code and tree builder code have opposite senses for how `left` and `right` should work.  Tree builder:

```
if (strcmp(node->data,newPtr->data)<0)
    node->left = addword(node->left,newPtr);
```

This will recurse left if the `node` is less than the `newPtr`.  This is opposite of what the tree recursion does:

```
    if (strcmp(key,node->data)<0)
        return _retrieve (key, node->left);
```

You need to flip one to match the other.  My preference would be to flip the builder, so that the left pointer is less than the parent, and the parent is less than the right node.

Comment: Thank you Joe for making my code shorter, but I'm sure tree building is right, because I have a display function that prints all nodes.

Comment: sorry change statement in builder to (strcmp(newPtr->data,node->data)<0) does not work, and if I change after condition  node->left = addword(newPtr,node->left); and node right it becomes a runtime error!thank you for patience! my mind is blown

Comment: @Beginner: when you changed the builder, all you needed to do was change the order of arguments to `strcmp`.  Beyond that, I'm not sure what to tell you.  Maybe add print statements in the "then" and "else clauses of your `if` statements to show your recursion steps the decisions your code is making.

Comment: Oh I forgot to close bracket after edit. Really I don't know how to thank you!